# Solve system of differential equation in python

Tags: scipy, precision, numerical-methods, differential-equations, odeint

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations in python.
I have a system composed by two equations where I have two variables, A and B.
The initial condition are that A0=1e17 and B0=0, they change simultaneously.
I wrote the following code using ODEINT:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dmdt(m,t):
    A, B = m

    dAdt = A-B
    dBdt = (A-B)*A

    return [dAdt, dBdt]

# Create time domain
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1)

# Initial condition
A0=1e17
B0=0

m0=[A0, B0]

solution = odeint(dmdt, m0, t)
```

Apparently I obtain an output different from the expected one but I don't understand the error.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `A*A'-B'=0` one concludes

```
B = 0.5*(A^2 - A0^2)
```

Inserted into the first equation that gives

```
A' = A - 0.5*A^2 + 0.5*A0^2
   = 0.5*(A0^2+1 - (A-1)^2)
```

This means that the `A` dynamic has two fixed points at about `A0+1` and `-A0+1`, is growing inside that interval, the upper fixed point is stable. However, in standard floating point numbers there is no difference between `1e17` and `1e17+1`. If you want to see the difference, you have to encode it separately.

Also note that the standard error tolerances `atol` and `rtol` in the range somewhere between `1e-6` and `1e-9` are totally incompatible with the scales of the problem as originally stated, also highlighting the need to rescale and shift the problem into a more appreciable range of values.

Setting `A = A0+u` with `|u|` in an expected scale of `1..10` then gives

```
B = 0.5*u*(2*A0+u)

u' = A0+u - 0.5*u*(2*A0+u) = (1-u)*A0 - 0.5*u^2
```

This now suggests that the time scale be reduced by `A0`, set `t=s/A0`. Also, `B = A0*v`. Insert the direct parametrizations into the original system to get

```
du/ds = dA/dt / A0 = (A0+u-A0*v)/A0            = 1 + u/A0 - v

dv/ds = dB/dt / A0^2 = (A0+u-A0*v)*(A0+u)/A0^2 =  (1+u/A0-v)*(1+u/A0)

u(0)=v(0)=0
```

Now in floating point and the expected range for `u`, we get `1+u/A0 == 1`, so effectively `u'(s)=v'(s)=1-v` which gives

```
u(s)=v(s)=1-exp(-s)`,

A(t) = A0 + 1-exp(-A0*t)  +  very small corrections
B(t) = A0*(1-exp(-A0*t))  +  very small corrections
```

The system in `s,u,v` should be well-computable by any solver in the default tolerances.